# how can i run cakephp website without app name in url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, routes

I have two app in cakephp2.1.3 vesion, one is admin and second is web, I want to run my website without my app name  like without 'web', current website url is 'http://localhost/cakephp2.1.3/web/customers/index' but i need to access using 'http://localhost/cakephp2.1.3/customers/index'.

My current .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ web/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) web/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and i have just change outer index.php

```
define('APP_DIR', 'web');
```

When i try to access 'http://localhost/cakephp2.1.3/customers/index' it gives error

```
Error: Cakephp-2.1.3Controller could not be found.
Error: Create the class Cakephp-2.1.3Controller below in file: web\Controller\Cakephp-2.1.3Controller.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot add a new domain and a new VirtualHost, look into apache's [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) that can map a url to a (different) filesystem location.

In your case you'll need something like this:

```
Alias /cakephp2.1.3 /cakephp2.1.3/web/
```

Comment: thats fine, but i also need it, when i go for live on my particular domain. then how can i run my website without 'web'?

Comment: You can configure apache the same way (assuming you're using apache there too).